# improper integral convergence with trig

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

Am i correct in saying that this integral converges.  I just broke the rational into two parts with 2 in the numerator in one and $\sin(x)$ in the other and this should clearly converge to 0 in both cases.

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2+\sin(x)}{ln(x)+5}dx$$

Comment: For sufficiently large $x$, the integrand is greater than $1/\log{x}$, so...

Comment: No. it is not convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>e^5$,

$$\ln (x)+5\le 2\ln (x) $$
and
$$2+\sin (x)\ge 1$$
thus

$$\frac {1+\sin (x)}{\ln (x)+5}\ge \frac {1}{2\ln (x)} $$

but

$$\lim_{+\infty}\frac {\sqrt {x}}{\ln (x)}=+\infty$$
thus for $x $ large enough

$$\frac {\sqrt {x}}{\ln (x)}\ge 1$$
and

$$\frac {1}{\ln (x)}\ge \frac {1}{\sqrt {x}} $$

finally, as $\int^{+\infty}\frac {dx}{\sqrt {x}} $ diverges, we conclude that your integral is Divergent.